# Flexbox flex-direction column bug

Tags: safari, flexbox, responsive

i have a big problem in responsive website in mobile safari and mobile ie or some mobile browsers. my site its ok in chrome mobile browser, but in ie or safari flex-direction column do not work and see parts lokelike float without clear. what i do for this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UCzn.jpg)

it's in true show and in mobile chrome browser

and its in ie and safari mobile browsers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3IJA.jpg)

this problem is for flex-direction:column

can see this problem in 10up.github.io/flexibility/

Comment: my demo website is ateniz.com / bezanimbiroon.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask